# Python Text to Search for Youtube videos Source Code

Tags: python-3.x, url, youtube

Python Noob here,

What this code does is it prints and opens in youtube all the urls.

I just want it to open the very first url it finds instead of all of them.

```
import urllib.request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import webbrowser

textToSearch = 'Hello World'
query = urllib.parse.quote(textToSearch)
url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + query
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for vid in soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'yt-uix-tile-link'}):
    print('https://www.youtube.com' + vid['href'])
    url = ('https://www.youtube.com/' + vid['href'])
    webbrowser.open(url)
    print('Done!')
```

I thought of changine the line

```
soup.findAll
```

to

```
soup.find
```

but it doesnt work:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

And i have no idea what to do, it must be something simple and i dont have much knowledge so if you can help me out i'd really appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the docs of BeautifulSoup

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

just add

`for vid in soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'yt-uix-tile-link'}`**, limit=1):**

so you'll return the first one.
find doesn't work i think because with those parameters vid becomes a string and in python you can't do

```
vid='whatever'
print vid['href']
```